# Multi Image carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

This is not a question. I wanted to post code that a partner of mine fixed. I searched and searched on how to create a multi-image carousel, but none of the code is working. Here is what we did:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="\static\carousel\c1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="\static\carousel\c2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="\static\carousel\c3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="\static\carousel\c4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="\static\carousel\c5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img
                            src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
            next=next.next();
            if (!next.length) {
                next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            }

            next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.carousel-control { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {
    margin-
    left:15px;background-
    image:none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  100%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -100%; }
   .active > div             { display:none;  }
   .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -50%; }
    .active > div                   { display:none;  }
    .active > div:first-child       { display:block; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  16.7%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -16.7%; }
}
.carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 0.10s ease-in-out left;
    -moz-transition: 0.10s ease-in-out left;
    -o-transition: 0.10s ease-in-out left;
    transition: 0.10s ease-in-out left;
}
```

Note the last item in the CSS file `.carousel-inner` adjusts the time before slides transition.

Original code:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Comment: This is a **question** and **answer** site. If you have something interesting to share, you are welcome to do so, but you must first post an actual question and follow up with an answer. You can then accept your own answer after a waiting period of 48 hours.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Maybe this solution helps you to fix your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640427/how-to-create-an-infinity-multi-item-image-carousel-touch-and-all-plain-vani/77640428#77640428